# Get Values based on column name Array

Tags: lodash

I have this array of objects
 main_obj = [{
         name: "Jason", age: 10
}, {     name: Jeff, age: 22}];

How can I get the age of Jason using Lodash? I tried _.map(main_obj, 'Jason') but didnt work.

Comment: you could use [`_.find()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#find)

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash [`find()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find) to search for the object where `name` = `"Jason"`. 
Use 'his' object to get the `.age`

```js
var main_obj = [{ name: "Jason", age: 10 }, { name: "Jeff", age: 22}];
var Jason = _.find(main_obj, { name: 'Jason' });
console.log(Jason.age);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.0.0/lodash.js"></script><script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```